# java pull second word in a string in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

i have an array of Strings, called food,
where

```
food[0] = "banana fruit"
food[1] = "potato vegetable"
food[2] = "peas vegetable"
food[3] = "apple fruit"
food[4] = "pumpkin vegetable"
```

how would i print *just* the vegetables?

Comment: This is really basic and can easily be solved with little effort via google

Comment: @EngineerDollery i looked and i couldn't find anything, otherwise i wouldn't have posted it. some people struggle with the simple tasks in java so i don't really think it's fair for you to make a comment like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `endsWith()` or `contains()` String methods:

```
for (String s : food) {
  if (s.endsWith("vegetable"))
    System.out.println(s);
}
```